# Fix PHP condition when decoding JSON

Tags: php, json

I'm decoding a json file using php.

In `foreach` statement I check if my cd_driver is in the array coming from the json file content. If it's in the array the script updates its month as expected. If not, the script writes the new driver into the json file.

Everything works fine but it's also executing the `else` condition after updating its month and adding the same driver to the json file. Why is this happening?

```
$dados[] = array('cd_driver' => $cd_driver, 'Driver' => $RSx["ds_name"], 'month' => $cd_month, 'bsaldo' => $saldoToJson);
$dados2 = array('cd_driver' => $cd_driver, 'Driver' => $RSx["ds_name"], 'month' => $cd_month, 'bsaldo' => $saldoToJson);
$jsonString = file_get_contents('bsaldo.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

    if($data == ""){
        $newString = json_encode($dados);
        file_put_contents('bsaldo.json', $newString);
    }else {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

            $mot = $value['cd_driver'];
            $array = array();
            array_push($array, $mot);

            if(in_array($cd_driver, $array)){
                $data[$key]['month'] = $cd_month;
                $newString = json_encode($data);
                file_put_contents('bsaldo.json', $newString);
            }else {
                array_push($data, $dados2);
                $finalString = json_encode($data);
                file_put_contents('bsaldo.json', $finalString);
            }

        }
    }
```

json:

```
[
    {
        "cd_driver": "11831",
        "Driver": "ADENILSON RODRIGUES DE SOUZA",
        "month": "02",
        "bsaldo": -903
    },
    {
        "cd_driver": "11835",
        "Driver": "EDIVAN DE CASTRO VASSALO",
        "month": "01",
        "bsaldo": -7670
    },
    {
        "cd_driver": "11831",
        "Driver": "ADENILSON RODRIGUES DE SOUZA",
        "month": "02",
        "bsaldo": -903
    },
    {
        "cd_driver": "11831",
        "Driver": "ADENILSON RODRIGUES DE SOUZA",
        "month": "02",
        "bsaldo": -903
    }
]
```

I had to adapt some things to work with php 5.1.

Comment: `$cd_driver` appears to be undefined in your code.  see `$mot = $value['cd_driver'];`  and you reset this `$array = array();` on every iteration.  so `[$mot]` is the same as that array.  OR `$cd_driver == $mot`

Comment: you empty $array in every loop

Comment: Essentially this is what you are doing, `if(undefined == $mot){` - :)  - instead of this `if(in_array($cd_driver, $array)){`  Which of course will fall down to the `}else{` part of the condition.

Comment: `I had to adapt some things to work with php 5.1`  PHP 5.x is pretty much done for, which reminds me I need to upgrade my server from `5.6`

Comment: What do you mean with `undefined`? Because of the loop? It updates the drivers to the file.

Comment: You haven't shown all the code – e.g. you haven't shown how $cd_driver and other variables are set.

Comment: They come from a query and are not empty or undefined. I always print my values to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are resetting the array on each iteration of the loop. Move it outside of the `foreach`, like so:

```
$dados[] = array('cd_driver' => $cd_driver, 'Driver' => $RSx["ds_name"], 'month' => $cd_month, 'bsaldo' => $saldoToJson);
$dados2 = array('cd_driver' => $cd_driver, 'Driver' => $RSx["ds_name"], 'month' => $cd_month, 'bsaldo' => $saldoToJson);
$jsonString = file_get_contents('bsaldo.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

    if($data == ""){
        $newString = json_encode($dados);
        file_put_contents('bsaldo.json', $newString);
    }else {
        $array = array(); # here it won't be continually reset and can accumulate values as intended.
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

            $mot = $value['cd_driver'];

            array_push($array, $mot);

            if(in_array($cd_driver, $array)){
                $data[$key]['month'] = $cd_month;
                $newString = json_encode($data);
                file_put_contents('bsaldo.json', $newString);
            }else {
                array_push($data, $dados2);
                $finalString = json_encode($data);
                file_put_contents('bsaldo.json', $finalString);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice. I should have done that already. It solved part of the problem. Now I need to find a way to move that `else` outside the loop because it's executing several times according to the number of registers found.

Comment: If that has solved your problem I suggest award a correct answer and ask a new question.

Comment: I think it's still part of the question but thanks anyway.